# Adding Google GCM Api Key Azure Notification Hub Error

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

We are trying to add our GCM API key to the azure notification hub and we are receiving the following error:

SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with GCM. Error is The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized...TrackingId:410c0e33-0c38-1823-8a62-2519627c76a2_M1_G19,TimeStamp:9/19/2014 10:08:32 AM

We have setup our GCM API key to allow any IP address and we have also tried registering from code like below but with the same error:

```
  NamespaceManager mgr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(conn);
  var hub = mgr.GetNotificationHub("<hubname>");


  hub.GcmCredential = new GcmCredential("<apikey>");
  mgr.UpdateNotificationHub(hub);
```

Are we missing something quite obvious here?

Comment: Sigh, I hadn't enabled Google cloud messaging for android.....

Answer (score 8):

```
SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with GCM.
```

This will probably fix this error:

Under the `SERVICES` tab in the APIs console for Google devs:

- **enable** Google cloud messaging for android

Comment: Rock star this will work 100% but for more clear I have post a new answer, cause cant attache picture over here. Thanks Crusher... !

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this problem and what I found was that I needed to go to the new firebase console, import my existing google project.

Once I had done that I could go to the settings cog in the top left->project settings.  Then click on the cloud messaging tab then get the new server key.  Once I entered that I was good to go in the notification hub.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CrusherJoe is 100% correct but if some one need more clear picture here I have attached the screenshot. just go to the link and enable it. [image]

Comment: There is not that option there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Some users may not have verified or registered domain.

With the help of webmaster Tools u can verify and register your domain.

Go to 
Google Dev Console -> your project ->API's and Auth -> Push -> Click on Learn more for webmaster